# Subclass a button within a custom class using SetWindowSubclass

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing

I am attempting to write a class to handle the creation of a button and it's messages internally.  I wish to keep all of the code contained within the class itself.  This may be simple or impossible as I am relatively new to Winapi and C++, having used vb.net much more extensively.  I was unable to find an example that accomplished this seeming simple conversion.  I did find examples suggesting i use an alternate API, or use SetWindowLongPtr, I am told that SetWindowSubclass is the better option.  My attempted code is below:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>

using namespace std;

    class button {
    public:
        bool initialize();
        buttton(int x, int y, int length, int width, LPCWSTR text, HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance);  // This is the constructor

    private:
        LPCWSTR text = L"Button";
        int height = 25;
        int width = 100;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        HWND parent;
        HWND thisHandle;
        HINSTANCE thisInstance;
        bool initialized = false;
        LRESULT CALLBACK mySubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);

    };


    button::button(int x, int y, int height, int width, LPCWSTR text, HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->height = height;
        this->width = width;
        this->text = text;
        this->parent = parent;
        thisInstance = hInstance;
    }
        bool button::initialize()
    {
        thisHandle = CreateWindowW(
            L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
            text,      // Button text 
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | BS_NOTIFY,  // Styles 
            x,         // x position 
            y,         // y position 
            width,        // Button width
            height,        // Button height
            parent,     // Parent window
            NULL,       // No ID.
            thisInstance,
            NULL);      // Pointer not needed.
        if (!thisHandle)
        {
            return false;
        }
        initialized = true;
        //Problem Code****
        SetWindowSubclass(thisHandle, mySubClassProc, 1, 0);
        //****  
        return true;
    }

    LRESULT CALLBACK button::mySubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {

        //Code handling messages here.
    }
}
```

This throws the error :

> argument of type "LRESULT (__stdcall button::*)(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)" is incompatible with parameter of type "SUBCLASSPROC"

I am hoping that someone can explain a simple solution, or suggest an alternative in Winapi, as i wish to learn native windows and C++ and not rely on additional libraries.

Comment: You still have a *lot* to learn about the differences between C and C++, subclassing is also not nearly enough to do this properly.   Do avoid re-inventing this wheel, there are many excellent C++ wrappers for the winapi.  Pick from, say, MFC, Qt, wxwidgets.  If you don't want to use them then at least look at what they do.

Comment: Declare your subclass procedure as `static`...

Comment: @Hans Passant: I do have a lot to learn. This particular code isn't intended to be used in a finished product but instead was attempting to explore possibilities. While "Re-inventing the wheel" seems pointless, I don't think that using the mentioned wrappers will give me a better understanding of the inner workings of Winapi. If subclassing isn't enough to do this properly can you suggest what I should be studying to accomplish something like this in native Winapi? Additionally, I will look into the suggested wrappers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use a **non-static class method** as the subclass callback.  That will not work, because a non-static class method has a hidden `this` parameter that the API will not be able to pass.

To do what you are attempting, you must remove the `this` parameter (you can use the  `dwRefData` parameter of `SetWindowSubclass()` instead), by either:

1. using a **static class method**:

   ```
   class button {
   public:
       bool initialize();
       ...

   private:
       ...

       static LRESULT CALLBACK mySubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);

   };

   bool button::initialize()
   {
       ...
       SetWindowSubclass(thisHandle, mySubClassProc, 1, (DWORD_PTR) this);
       return true;
   }

   LRESULT CALLBACK button::mySubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
   {
       button *pThis = (button*) dwRefData;

       //Code handling messages here.
   }
   ```
2. using a **non-member function**:

   ```
   class button {
   public:
       bool initialize();
       ...
   };

   LRESULT CALLBACK myButtonSubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
   {
       button *pBtn = (button*) dwRefData;
       //Code handling messages here.
   }

   bool button::initialize()
   {
       ...
       SetWindowSubclass(thisHandle, myButtonSubClassProc, 1, (DWORD_PTR) this);
       return true;
   }
   ```